# How to handle heavy application jar in java web start jnlp?

Tags: javafx-2, java-7, java-web-start, jnlp, tomcat8

I'm new to Java FX programming. 
I'm using JDK 7 and JavaFX and using javafxpackager to create and deploy my JavaFX application. When I do so the my app jar is created without any dependency jars and hence its size is in KBs. When I deploy this to tomcat 8 server and access, it gives me NOClassDefFoundError for *Application* class (of javaFX package).

When I build the jar (using ant) in traditional way with all dependency jars packaged and this when deployed and accessed gives *IOException* saying file size is too high (its about 20MB)

Please let me know how to go about this.
Any help is much appreciated.

THANKS

Comment: Did you try packaging the dependencies in separate jars? in your JNLP you can include more than one jar...

Comment: @foch.. Thanks. Now in my jnlp, I'm using multiple <resouces...> tag for each of the dependency jar.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, put all depending JARs into the JNLP:

Example:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="Test.jnlp">
   <information>
     <title>Jnlp Testing</title>
     <vendor>Test</vendor>
     <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/" />
     <description>Test</description>
   </information>
   <security>
    <all-permissions/>
   </security>
      <resources>
         <j2se version="1.6+" />
         <jar href="Test.jar" />
         <jar href="Lib1.jar" />
         <jar href="Lib2.jar" />
         <jar href="Lib3.jar" />
         <jar href="Lib4.jar" />
      </resources>
   <application-desc main-class="com.test.Main" />
</jnlp>
```

see here fore more details: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html
and here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlpFileSyntax.html